# How do I store assets for javascript on the web?

Tags: javascript, audio

Recently I have been trying to create a chat project which makes a ringing noise once you receive a message. My problem is that I cannot find a ringing noise that will be available for the project anywhere. Google drive does not work, the javascript can't process it. For some reason if I link sound from wikipedia it does work. Is there a way to upload a ringing sound which will be available to link to through javascript?
Thanks!
P.S. I'm sorry about how long this question is, congratulations if you read it & managed to understand what I'm saying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a bit of overhead but you can use something like this to have an easy access to your audio:
http://www.createjs.com/soundjs

In a theoretical sense you would have your assets (be it soundfiles or images or what ever) loaded to the webserver you serve your page from. Normaly you will have an assets folder on there. You can then access these files by using the path to that folder on your server in your code.

HTML5 should provide functions for sound playback and such as well. Might as well start there

Comment: I am currently coding using a website called codepen, and it doesn't let me have an asset folder unless I upgrade my account. Do you know a better place to write my code?

Comment: You can use any text editor for Javascript coding. I prefer something like atom.io. Your code can just lay on your hard disk. Now you can create a basic HTML file and open it in your browser.

Comment: If this answer helped you out and answered your question please mark it as the correct answer :)